# Getting bash to ignore bash keywords in a script

Tags: bash, keyword

I have a script in `bash` which uses the `HTK toolkit`. One of the files that the HTK tool uses is called `do` and is present within a directory called `hmm_1/`. Now, when I need to call a particular tool from within the HTK toolkit, I do it like so:

`some HTK command -H hmm_1/do -H hmm_1/<something else>` and so on. I just noticed that `gvim` highlights the `do` *file name* in the above command, thinking it is a keyword. However, it is a file name. My question is:

1. Will bash interpret it as a keyword or does bash know better (it is just a gvim quirk).
2. How can I get bash to "know" that some variable names, though innocuously named like keywords are not that and are instead filenames?

Note: I cannot change the name of the file now. I will have to backtrack through a large number of steps.

I just don't know how to phrase this question. Help in editing the question line is most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of a path, keywords will be ignored. They will only be interpreted as a keyword at the beginning of a command. It would be best to simply consider `gvim`'s highlighting to be a minor annoyance and ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Other than using the command as part of an explicit path (like Ernest proposed, and what will do in your case), you can also use the `command` builtin to search commands which are in some directory in the `$PATH` variable, ignoring aliases, shell functions and shell keywords:

```
$ echo '#!/bin/bash
> echo Hello World!' > ~/bin/do

$ chmod u+x ~/bin/do
```

`~/bin` is in my path, thus this would normally work:

```
$ do
bash: Syntaxfehler beim unerwarteten Wort `do'
```

It does not, since it is a reserved word. Prefixing it with `command` helps:

```
$ command do
Hello World!
```

As does using the full path:

```
$ ~/bin/do
Hello World!
```